# Why do Bootstrap components appear nicer on FontAwesome website?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm wondering why components appear nicer on FontAwesome's website then in mine (it's not yet online, so you cannot see yourself... but you can check Bootstrap's website's [button section](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons)).

I just tried to cut and paste the snippet for the *delete button* (the one in red) at the [example page](http://fontawesome.io/examples/) and the look and feel is not the same: of course the font is different, but I also notice that nice light/shadow effect on the borders of the button is clearer than on buttons made with Bootstrap.

I thought, there must be an additional external component able to give that look and feel to  the button, but I'd like to know what it is. I checked the source and I noticed the reference to a library from typekit.com that could have been a candidate to the answer I'm looking for, but it seems to be about fonts.

Another option is the author of FA website pimped Bootstrap CSS or JS to give that effect, but after checking the source I found nothing.

Any idea how to get the same light/shadow effect on button borders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you whip out your handy document inspector (F12 in Windows), you can see that Font Awesome has applied their fonts to Bootstrap's button, which contains CSS like the following:

```
.btn-primary, .btn-success, .btn-warning, .btn-danger, .btn-info {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

This adds the text shadow of which you speak. Borders are similarly styled by Bootstrap:

```
.btn-danger {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #d9534f;
    border-color: #d43f3a;
}
```

Other variations may be due to differing Bootstrap versions, overriding custom CSS, etc.

Comment: Just a couple of questions: #1 your hint gives shadow to the text in the button and not to its borders. How to do that? #2 What's the document inspector you're talking about? Notice I'm not a front end developer, I'm from the other side so CSS and browsers' tools are a total mystery to me. Be patient...

Comment: No worries... I found out 'box-shadow' do the work !

Comment: Modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE11) have very useful developer tools built in. Look into how to use the inspector to see what CSS is applied to a particular element. I think you'll find this invaluable.